# Function is casting uint8 <-->uint16?

Tags: c, casting

I'm unit testing(UT) my code and I found something odd that maybe someone can explain to me.
I have two functions similar to those beneath this lines. When I call "fun_16bit" from the test I pass a value above 255 to see what "fun_8bit" does. If I write value=256 -->fun_8bit will print 0. If I call from UT fun_8bit with value=-1-->It prints 255.

What is happening?????
Why the func8bit does only take the first 8 bits and doesn't the compiler say something?

By the way I'm compiling C with gcc.

```
void fun_16bit(uint16_t value)
{
    printf("value: %d", value);
    fun_8bit(value);
}

void fun_8bit(uint8_t value)
{
    printf("value: %d", value);
}



int main() {
  fun_16bit(0x1234);
}
```

Expected output: some error from compiler or warning
Actual output:
value: 1234
value: 34

Thankyou all.

Comment: True, I will edit

Comment: Please show actual and expected output.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking about the following conversion.

- `(uint16_t)-1` resulting in `65535`
- `(uint8_t)-1` resulting in `255`
- `(uint8_t)65535` resulting in `255`

These results are required by the C spec.

> 6.3.1.3  Signed and unsigned integers
>
> 1. When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than `_Bool`, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
> 2. Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, **the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.**<sup>[60]</sup>
> 3. Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it;  either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

(Emphasis mine)

- `(uint16_t)-1` is equivalent to `(uint16_t)65535` because `-1 + 65536*1 = 65535`.
- `(uint8_t)-1` is equivalent to `(uint8_t)255` because `-1 + 256*1 = 255`.
- `(uint8_t)65535` is equivalent to `(uint8_t)255` because `65535 - 256*255 = 255`.

In effect, on a two's-complement machine,

- Converting to `uint16_t` takes the last 16 bits.
- Converting to `uint8_t` takes the last 8 bits.

`gcc` doesn't normally warn about narrowing type conversions and signed-to-unsigned type conversions, but `-Wconversion` will enable such warnings.

Answer (score 0):

256 means that the first 8 bits from your number are 0 and the 9th is 1. when you convert it to an uint8_t for fun_8bit, you function only sees the 8 bits with 0. As for the second case, -1 for an uint means all bits as 1. in fun_16bit that means 16 bits of 1. when you convert it to uint8_t, you get 8 bits of 1 (meaning 255)

Comment: But why func_8bit is casting or taking only the first 8 bits? The compiler should say something, no?

Comment: depend on the flags you give to the compiler. -Wall and -pedantic should say something

Comment: @GeorgeGlavan actually they don't: https://www.godbolt.org/z/ncbfcWPrs

Comment: yeah, just found out to .. strange.

Comment: it looks like -Wconversion is the option (dont know why it is not enabled by -Wall ...)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the issue here:

Let's have a look at some numbers here:

- `uint8_t` just takes the last eight digits of the binary format, while `uint16_t` takes the last sixteen.
- `-1` is defined as the value where you need to add 1 in order to get 0, there is no standard way of writing this in binary format.

This is the result:

```
Decimal value    Binary value     uint8_t value    uint16_t value
          256       100000000          00000000  0000000100000000
          255        11111111          11111111  0000000011111111
           -1          11...1          11111111  1111111111111111
```

So, as you can see:
256 in binary format is a 1, followed by eight 0 digits. When you take the last eight digits (converting to `uint8_t`), you just get zero.
255 is just a bunch of 1 digits, which is the same as -1 in `uint8_t` format.
If you want -1 in `uint16_t`, 65535 is the number you'll need.

Comment: So in my example fun_8bit is casting from 16bit to 8 bit. 
I think the proper should be to write --> fun_8bit((uint8_t)value);

Comment: @yaviens: this is the same indeed, but clearer for the one who needs to read (or maintain) it. I believe the best way to understand this is saying that `fun8` takes the last eight bits, while `fun16` takes the last sixteen.